# Unable to find remote helper for https

Tags: git

I was trying to connect my remote repository to my local one. In terminal instead of writing "https", I accidentally typed "hhtps". Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: How did you write that? What command? If it's a git, you should be able to read the config file, and there are command to remove/add url.

Comment: git remote add origin hhtps://github.com/"myusername"/''myapp".git

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/removing-a-remote/ ? You should be able to remove it, and then add the correct one.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: [`git help remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) knows all the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the URL of a remote using `git remote set-url`.

```
# Create a remote with the wrong URL
git remote add origin hhtps://github.com/myusername/myapp.git

# Fix the URL
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myusername/myapp.git
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit url for the remote in .git/config

Comment: i see people have been down-voting this answer. Cases like this (fix a typo), I work them up on the config file directly. Just saying...